# If magnetic induction vector will not be perpendicular to charge velocity, there will be work?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, work

The work is $A=FS$

The force is $F=q[E+v\times B]$

The $v \times B$ is a new vector, $|v||B|\sin\space \alpha$

Let's consider the next case:
[image]

Where red dot is a particle, moving due to $v$. We **do not** have $90$ degree angle, hence we don't get $0$ in $v\times B$, and hence the force isn't $0$, and hence the work is doing.

I am correct?

Comment: Can you kindly draw also the velocity $v$?

Comment: @the_candyman, Ah, I've done mistake - v, instead of E. I edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the angle between the magnetic field vector and the velocity vector of the moving charge is less than $90^\circ$, the magnitude of the cross-product will be reduced as per formula you've provided $(|F|=|v||B|\sin\space\alpha)$.

However, that does not affect the direction of the force (i.e., direction of the cross-product vector) - it will still be normal to the plane formed by the two vectors and, therefore, normal to the velocity vector. Therefore, the work performed by the force will still be zero.

Comment: Wait a minute, You're contracting math. You said - "work will be zer0". Again, work is $F*S$, so which of multipliers is zero in Your opinion?

Comment: @Artur The formula for the work is equal to the dot product of vectors $F$ and $S$: $|F||S|\cos\alpha$, so, if $F$ is normal to $S$, the product is zero, even if both vectors are not zero.

Comment: Why $S$ perpendicular to $F$?

Comment: @Artur Because $F$ is perpendicular to $v$ (velocity) and that is because $F$ is a cross-product of $B$ and $v$ and the direction of a cross-product vector is defined as normal to both vectors.

Comment: Well, okay.....